# Sharepoint Querying a list with paging

Tags: sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2010

I'm using SOAP UI to query the Sharepoint List. Here is my **updated ** SOAP Request:

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soap:GetListItems>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:listName>Example</soap:listName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:viewName>{AAAAA-AAAA-AAA-AAAAA}</soap:viewName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:query>
            <Query>
            </Query>
         </soap:query>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:viewFields>
            <ViewFields>
                <FieldRef Name="Author" />
                    <FieldRef Name="ContentType" />
                    <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />
            </ViewFields>
         </soap:viewFields>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:rowLimit>1000</soap:rowLimit>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:queryOptions>
            <QueryOptions>
                   <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/>
            </QueryOptions>
         </soap:queryOptions>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <soap:webID></soap:webID>
      </soap:GetListItems>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I get the below error when I run this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <errorstring xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">The query cannot be completed because the number of lookup columns it contains exceeds the lookup column threshold enforced by the administrator.Operations that exceed the list view threshold are allowed in the following time window defined by the administrator: &lt;br/>&lt;b>Daily, from  7:00:00 PM to 11:00:00 PM . &lt;/b></errorstring>
            <errorcode xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">0x80070093</errorcode>
         </detail>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I can access the List during the hours mentioned in the error but is there any way through pagination or something else that will allow to access this list during outside of these hours? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is complaining not about the number of results but about the number of **lookup columns** displayed in the view.

When you include lookup columns in your CAML query, SharePoint has to do some extra work behind the scenes to query the related lists and pull in the relevant information. This can impact database performance, so SharePoint puts a default limit of 8 lookup columns on each query during business hours. (In SharePoint 2013 this is expanded to 12.) For more details, see [this Microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/12/02/sharepoint-20102013-list-view-lookup-threshold-uncovered/).

Note that as far as the threshold is concerned "lookup columns" includes columns of type **Lookup** and **Person or Group**, as well as **Workflow Status** columns.

To perform your query during business hours, you can remove columns from your view until the view no longer shows more than 8 lookup columns.

Comment: Hi Thriggle, thanks for your reply. I do not have administrator access to this list. Do I need to be an administrator to modify this columns?

Comment: In your SOAP message you're specifying the GUID of a view. `<soap:viewName>{AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAAAA}</soap:viewName>` If you cannot edit that view or create a different view, then you can instead modify your SOAP to specify the `<ViewFields>` that you want, being sure to include no more than 8 lookup fields.

Comment: Okay, I will try to add viewFields and see if that helps. Thanks a lot Thriggle.

Comment: You're welcome. You can refer to [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248000/why-does-viewfields-criteria-get-ignored-by-the-sharepoint-list-services-getl) for syntax.

Comment: Hi Thriggle, I updated my SOAP request with the viewFields but it gives me the same error.

Comment: You probably need to remove or replace `<soap:viewName>` or that will override your specified view fields.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even after making the changes as you described.

Comment: There may be some other problem with the syntax of your query, in which case SharePoint usually tries to give you the default view of the list, often ignoring whatever is specified in the CAML query. If the default view has 8+ lookup columns, you'd see that same error. My initial guess is that the internal names of the fields should **not** have the "ows_" prefix. You might also need to specify the [`ViewFieldsOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.viewfieldsonly(v=office.14).aspx) property.

Comment: Hi Thriggle, I get the response now if I don't use recursive all attribute. Is there a way to provide folder path in the query? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Thriggle for your assistance.